# Could we have link underlines in different/complementary colours to the text?

Tags: feature-request, design

While whinging about the underlines on text, I pointed out that [this site's design worked well](https://offspring.lifehacker.com/teach-kids-to-tie-their-shoes-with-the-big-loops-trick-1828838854), but I couldn't quite put my finger on it.

A bunch of folks pointed out a few technical details - that it was a shadow, not an underline, but since it is a different colour than the text it flowed a little better.

1. We can actually have obvious links without having the text in different colours - what folks felt was very 1990s web 1.0.
2. In languages with diacritics and bits that hang under the text, it's more obvious that it's one link

Here's a small example:

[image]

It looks a lot better, solves *one* critique people have of the design - since the text stands out less yet is an obvious link

I don't know much CSS (and less of [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29)), so I don't now if we could change the underline colour for clicked links (which would solve a second), but could we consider this as an alternative way to handle links?

Comment: The way lifehacker.com does it, the links also change colour on hover, which would help accessibility a bit.

Comment: If they can change on hover then it seems very likely that they can change if visited.

Comment: Bit I don't like about this style: it writes over the descenders rather than breaking nicely for them as native underlining does.

Comment: I personally prefer that, but to each their own